# Find values between numeric or alpha range

Tags: c#, regex, range

I have ranges defined as strings like the following:

```
[a-d]
[A-H]
[c,d]
[B,C]
[03-05]
```

How would I find the values in between such that the output be something like this?

```
[a-d]
a
b
c
d

[A-H]
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H

[c,d]
c
d

[B,C]
B
C

[03-05]  
03
04
05
```

I'm using this regular expression for parsing the ranges:

```
\[(.?+)[,|-](.?+)\]
```

Sometimes the ranges only contain two numbers or two letters therefore the comma notation is used.

My thought for the numbers is to start from the lowest number in the range and increment by one in a for loop  until the end of the range. However, it's not exactly that straight forward for alphabet characters unless I do a conversion to an `int` and run a for loop and cast the `int` back to a char.

Comment: You can also use a `for` loop with a `char` variable like this: `for(char c = 'a' ; c <= 'z'; c++) { /* your code */ }`. There is no need to convert to `int`s.

Comment: Seems like you already have an answer.  Just write an implementation for it and see if your idea works. If it does, great, if not, post it here along with the details of the problems with that solution.

Comment: Good points. I just wasn't sure if I needed to cast to int first or if I could do a for loop directly on chars.

Comment: The regex engine at http://regexpal.com/ doesn't recognize `[03-05]` as doing what you want. Is this valid in the regex you're trying to use, or is this some sort of custom format?

Comment: @TimS. That's his input data, not a regex.

Comment: you have your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957069/get-the-letters-abcde-between-two-letters-ae-using-c-sharp

Comment: @Servy Oh, my mistake! I was confused by the presence of `[]`, thinking that was regex as well.

Comment: @TimS. It looks like my regex doesn't match `[03-05]`. I thought that the `(.+?)` would match anything in the range. I'll have to modify to get it work with numeric ranges with leading zeros.

Comment: Somehow I confused `(.+?)` with `(.?+)` and switching the order of the `?` with the `+` made the regex match `[03-05]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% but nearly :)

```
var rangeStrings = new List<string> { "[a-d]", "[A-H]", "[c,d]", "[B,C]", "[03-05]" };
var separator = new[] { "-", "," };
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> ranges = rangeStrings
    .Select(rs =>
    {
        string inner = rs.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
        string[] token = inner.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        bool isNumeric = token[0].All(Char.IsDigit);
        int start, end;
        if(isNumeric)
        {
            start = int.Parse(token.First());
            end = int.Parse(token.Last());
        }
        else
        {
            start = (int)token.First().First();
            end = (int)token.Last().Last();
        }
        var range = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start + 1)
            .Select(i => isNumeric ? i.ToString() : ((Char)i).ToString());
        return range;
    });

foreach (var range in ranges)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Range: {0}", string.Join(",", range));
}
```

Output:

```
Range: a,b,c,d
Range: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
Range: c,d
Range: B,C
Range: 3,4,5  // <-- this makes problems
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/GChcWD)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! This is a very nice and elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

> My thought for the numbers is to start from the lowest number in the range and increment by one in a for loop until the end of the range. However, it's not exactly that straight forward for alphabet characters unless I do a conversion to an int and run a for loop and cast the int back to a char.

That would do the trick, but if you need your numerical values to have leading zeros for single digit numbers you can to use `String.Format` to get them back to the `"01"` style value.